# sorting csv data by column C#

Tags: c#

Hi I have a csv file like

```
Id Name Age 
1  John 44
```

I have write code for Altering data and saving as a new file. I need not to alter but to sort that data by Age ascending. Plz help I need it!!!
Here is my code.

```
private void buttonAlterSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string[]> parsedData = ReadAndtParsedata(@"C:....data.csv", ',');
    foreach (string[] row in parsedData)
    {
        if (row != parsedData[0])
        {
            string name = (row[1].Replace("\"", ""));
            string[] temp = name.Split();
            var sb = new StringBuilder(temp.LastOrDefault());
            sb.Append(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(temp[i]);
            }
            sb.Insert(0, "\"");
            sb.Append("\"");

            row[1] = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:....altereddata.csv"))
    {
        foreach (string[] row in parsedData)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in row)
            {
                sb.Append(s + ";");
            }
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);                 
            sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
var sorted = 
    File.ReadLines(inputPath)
        .Select(line => new { 
            SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[2]),
            Line = line 
         })
        .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey)
        .Select(x => x.Line);
File.WriteAllLines(outputPath, sorted)
```

Comment: Thnx, but occurs an error:{"Input string was not in a correct format."}. I mean what I have to change in my code to do the sort of data I do not need altering data

Comment: @bali katravella: Then debug it. You specified CSV, and that the third column is age. The error message you're providing implies that for one of the rows, the third column did not parse correctly to an integer. That suggests to me you haven't correctly specified the format of your data, or one of your rows does not conform to your specification. Your code suggests and example data suggests that the separator is `' '` instead of `','`; if that's the case merely change the `','` in my code to split on white space. My code does not alter your data.

Comment: Thnx Jason, my mistake I did not write all the columns: the csv file has 5 columns: Id Name Surname Age Salary. I tried debug it but no success I'm new in c#. Thank you one more time.